# Block incoming traffic from specific ip address

Tags: windows-xp, ip-address, blocking

How do I block incoming connections from a specific IP address in Windows XP without installing a firewall?

I've found this: http://www.ehow.com/how_5038640_block-ip-address-windows-xp.html
But I can't figure out how to do it? Step 3 seems to block all traffic on a specific port/protocol?
What GUI is he talking about in step 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following guide: http://www.petri.co.il/block_web_browsing_with_ipsec.htm